# Ruby Timezone String to java Timezone

Tags: java, ruby, timezone

I have a ruby process that writes to DB timezones according to [ruby TimeZone Class](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) so at the table I get strings such as:

- "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
- "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
- "UTC"
- "Paris"

and so on .. 
Is there a way (not hard coded map) to read those strings and convert them into [java Timezone instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)?

Comment: There is no built-in easy way. I don’t know of any external library or database that might help, I would search for one, though.

Comment: Aren’t you migrating to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)? The `TimeZone` class is long outdated and poorly designed, and it friends, like `Calendar` and `DateFormat`, are yet worse. The modern API is so much nicer to work with. The class you want for time zones is `ZoneId`.

Comment: Your problem is that whoever wrote the Ruby program confused presentation and storage and saved user-friendly strings to the database instead of strings suitable for programs. If you could persuade Ruby to save strings like `America/New_York`, you’d be better off (i.e., *region/city*). The page you link to seems to indicate that Ruby knows such strings too, but I don’t know how this works. If you can’t afford to change the existing DB column, maybe you can add a redundant one with the proper format? Or better, a conversion table?

Comment: Agreed with @OleV.V.; just a couple of notes. a) This is not Ruby, but Rails. b) The TimeZone::MAPPING is right there on the linked page; just translate it into Java `TreeMap`or something and Java can `TimeZone.getTimeZone(railsTimezoneMapping[railsName])`.

Comment: Thank you all, I guess I will use ZoneId (thanks to @OleV.V.), and write it hard coded since I can't touch the rails code (others are using it and it is too expensive to refactor).

Comment: Since I already wrote it if someone need it it is here (in scala :) https://gist.github.com/ehudl/3e6ded0d4557d7beb34ad9ea17c3a682

Answer (score 2):

The authoritative source for Rails time zone names to standard TZDB/IANA time zone identifiers is the `TimeZone.MAPPING` constant in the Rails source code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb).  If you are able to access this mapping in your Rails code, then you don't need to hardcode anything.

If rather (as it appears in the question comments) that you need to do the translation in your Java code, then you'll have to parse this mapping from the Rails code into something usable in your Java code, and periodically check for changes.   Thankfully, the Rails developers don't seem to change this list often.

I don't know of a Java library that already does this for you, but .NET developers can take advantage of my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library, which imports this mapping.  If you want to write your own code for this, feel free to translate my [`LoadRailsMapping`](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter/blob/aa041f9422b06fc5b3c94b6ebb2d80262291f6b8/src/TimeZoneConverter.DataBuilder/DataExtractor.cs#L128-L150) function from C# to Java.

See also my notes on Rails time zone names at the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).